# How can I better navigate through SQL commands in a script in the Toad for Oracle editor?

Tags: toad

Let's say I have a script that looks like this:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE schema1.tbl_1;
INSERT INTO schema1.tbl_1 (emp_id, state, emp_name)
   SELECT *
   FROM employees
   WHERE emp_id IN (1,2,3)

TRUNCATE TABLE schema1.tbl_2;
INSERT INTO schema1.tbl_2 (emp_id, state, emp_name)
   SELECT *
   FROM tbl_1
   WHERE state IN (1,2,3)

.And so on
.And so forth
.And so on
```

So I have lots of these truncate commands followed by insert commands. Like at least 20 of them.

Is there a way I can better navigate through these statements other than just having to painfully scroll through?

I looked into code folding, but from what I've seen Toad for Oracle handles what code you can fold automatically so I can't choose what sections of code I want to fold.

I looked into bookmarks, but it seems I'm limited to 10 of them and I can't name them.

I looked into the 'Navigator' window, but it isn't specific enough.

I looked into anonymous blocks, but that also doesn't seem to be what I want.

Is there really nothing to help me more easily navigate through this large script?

Comment: Regarding Code Folding... If you are on a newer version of Toad select the text range you want to hide and right-click "Hide Lines."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> can be used to cycle through statements.

You can also use the good old fashioned <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>PageDown</kbd> to scroll an entire page at a time. This is likely much faster than using the above method that only scrolls one complete command at a time.